# Recommendations for Facebook API Tutorials / Tips

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm mostly a .Net and JavaScript developer, and for those topics, I've picked from a large pool of blogs and tweets to follow for tutorials and tips.  I haven't found anything comparable for Facebook api development.  Can you make recommendations for good facebook api blogs and tweets for tutorials and tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source .Net sdk called [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).
The samples included are a good source for tips as well as some of the contributor's blogs [here](http://blog.prabir.me/) and [here](http://ntotten.com/).
The documentation for the Javascript SDK is reasonable but I have found the [Dev Wiki](http://fbdevwiki.com) helpful.